# Как вставить текст в элемент которой нет конкретного ID в браузере Awesomium?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, awesomium

Я использовал этот код (vb.net):

```
 WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('email').value = """ & TextBox1.Text & """")
```

чтобы вставить текст например сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всьо прикрасно работало.
А здесь уже отсутствует ID. Пожалуйста если кто то знает как это сделать, то пусть напишет. Я уже перепробовал около 25 вариаций, но ни одна несработала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
var z = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
 for (i=0;i<z.length;i++){
  if (z[i].getAttribute("data-text") == "true" && z[i].innerHTML == "Пример")
   z[i].innerHTML = "123";
 }
<html>
<body>
<span data-text="false">Пример</span><br>
<span data-text="true">Примёр</span><br>
<span data-text="true">Пример</span><br>
<span data-value="true">Пример</span><br>
<span>Пример</span><br>
<span data-text="true"></span><br>
</body>
</html>
```